# Jquery Dynatree plugin using clicks in id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Firebug I have found that the Dynatree plugin changes the following code:

```
<li id="id3.1" class="expanded">Menu 1
  <ul>
        <li id="id3.1.1">Sub-menu 1</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

To this:

```
<li class="">
   <span class="dynatree-node dynatree-exp-c dynatree-ico-c">
   <span class="dynatree-connector"></span>
   <span class="dynatree-icon"></span>
      <a class="dynatree-title" href="#">Sub-menu 1</a>
   </span>
</li>
```

So when I try to make a click event on the `id="id3.1.1"` nothing happens because this id doesn't exist anymore.

I made a search here and found the `onActivate` option that will make my click happen on the menu:

```
$("#treeMenu").dynatree({
    onActivate: function(node){
        var menuTitle = node.data.title;
        alert(menuTitle);
    }
});
```

My question: Is this the only way to do the click event using Dynatree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I think that is the best option, because it uses the API of the plugin, but of course you could still attach an event to the `<a>` like this:

```
$('a.dynatree-title').live('click', function(e){
     //here e.target is the link you have clicked
});
```

Comment: yes, what do you suggest, usign the api, a switch with a case for each menu?

Comment: yes i think that's a good option )but i'm no expert of dynatree, in any case using the api it's much better, also because usually when you upgrade the plugin the API stay consistent, the html markup doesn't)

Comment: Note that there is also the 'onClick' event, that will be triggered on every click, whereas onActivate is only fired when the node was newly acitvated.

Comment: If you set the 'generateIds' option to true, the node ID will be retained in the generated HTML code. Anyway, as Nicola suggested, using the API events is recommended (Btw: as far as I know '.' are not allowed in IDs according to the RFC)